# sed command: search and replace variables with \n character

Tags: bash, search, sed, replace, newline

I have to variables in a bash script:

```
    $string = "The cat is green.\n"
    $line = "Sunny day today.\n"
```

each of those variables contain "\n" character, how can I use sed to search and replace:

```
    sed 's/$string/$line/g' file.txt
```

This doesn't seem to work, if I erase the "\n" from the strings sed works properly.
If I had only the text I could escape "\n" by adding a backslash:

```
    sed 's/"The cat is green.\\n"/"Sunny day today.\\n"/g' file.txt
```

How can I manage to do search/replace when variables contain "\n" in them.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Could you show the exact format of `file.txt`?  `sed` reads a line at a time, a multi-line match can be done, but it is fiddly using the hold space.  By the way, using single quotes around `'s/$string/$line/g' ` means that the variables will not be substituted, it will look for literal `$string`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to match the *two-character* sequence `\n`, as opposed to the single newline character that together they represent in some contexts.  There is a tremendous difference between these.

As part of your example, you presented

> ```
> sed 's/$string/$line/g' file.txt
> ```

, but that won't work at all, because variable references are not expanded within single-quoted strings.  That has nothing whatever to do with the values of shell variables `string` and `line`.

But let's consider those values:

> ```
> $string="The cat is green.\n"
> $line="Sunny day today.\n"
> ```

[Extra spaces removed.]

Of course, the problem you're focusing on is that `sed` recognizes `\n` as a code for a newline character, but you also have the problem that in a regular expression, the `.` character matches *any* character, so if you want it to be treated as a literal then it, too, needs to be escaped (in the pattern, but not in the replacement).  If you're trying to support search and replace for arbitrary text, then there are other characters you'll need to escape, too.

Answering the question as posed (escaping only `\n` sequences) you might do this:

```
sed "s/${string//\\n/\\\\n}/${line//\\n/\\\\n}/g"
```

The `${foo//pat/repl}` form of parameter expansion performs pattern substitution on the expanded value, but note well that the pattern (`pat`) is interpreted according to shell globbing rules, not as a regular expression.  That specific form replaces every appearance of the pattern; read the bash manual for alternatives that match only the first appearance and/or that match only at the beginning or the end of the parameter's value.  Note, too, the extra doubling of the `\` characters in the pattern substitution -- they need to be escaped for the shell, too.

Given your variable definitions, that command would be equivalent to this:

```
sed 's/The cat is green.\\n/Sunny day today.\\n/g'
```

In other words, exactly what you wanted.  Again, however, be warned: that is not a general solution for arbitrary search & replace.  If you want *that*, then you'll want to study the `sed` manual to determine which characters need to be escaped in the regex, and which need to be escaped in the replacement.  Moreover, I don't see a way to do it with just one pattern substitution for each variable.